# How to toggle a class onclick event to only a <li> element in a list of lis using Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, vuejs2

I am studying a bit of Vuejs to up my game in the JS ecosystem. I am building a to-do list. I have managed to render a list of lis. I was also able to checked them using onlick event. However, when I clicked on a li it applied the class to all of them.

I tried looping through the list but I don't think I am doing it right. If anybody kindly could set me in the right direction please.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  <ul>
    <li v-bind:class="{ completed: isActive }" v-on:click="checked" v-for="todo in todos">
      {{ todo.task }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'List of things to do today',
    todos: [
      { task: 'Have breakfast' },
      { task: 'Go to the gym' },
      { task: 'Study Vuejs' }
    ],
    isActive: false
  },
  methods: {
    checked: function(todos){
      this.isActive = !this.isActive
    }
  }
});
```

I need to find a way to toggle the class in only the li that I click on...

Here is a a JSfiddle sample: https://jsfiddle.net/mercenariomode/pL3g6q14/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the click to modify `isActive` of `todo`, then you should store it (and read from) there:

```html
<li v-for="todo in todos"
    :class="{ completed: todo.isActive }"
    @click="$set(todo, 'isActive', !todo.isActive)">
  {{ todo.task }}
</li>
```

```js
data: {
  message: 'List of things to do today',
  todos: [
    { task: 'Have breakfast'},
    { task: 'Go to the gym'},
    { task: 'Study Vuejs'}
  ],
}
```

You don't need `isActive` in initial `todo`'s state, that is covered by using `$set`.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iStyx/508bn4se/

---

**Explanation about using `$set`:**

Initially, `todo` object doesn't have `isActive` property, so adding or changing it afterwards will *not* be reactive. Of course, you can add `isActive: false` to all of your `todo` objects, but that is quite messy and sloppy. Another way is to use [`Vue.$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) method (could be called from Vue instances by `this.$set`) which should be used to add new properties to reactive object (it also makes them reactive). Excerpt from the doc:

> Adds a property to a reactive object, ensuring the new property is also reactive, so triggers view updates. This must be used to add new properties to reactive objects, as Vue cannot detect normal property additions

Useful link to read: [Vue.js → Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Do you mind explaining me a bit more the `$set()` method?

Comment: Thank you very much. I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you make you todos an array of tuples or objects, like so:

```
 todos: [
        { task: ‘Have Breakfast’, isActive: false},
        // etc...
 ]
```

Then in your checked method, filter for the todo matching the name and only change that property:

```
checked: function(task) {
      this.todos.filter((todo) => todo.task === task)
          .forEach((match) => match.isActive = !match.isActive)
}
```

Which then allows you to add this to your template:

```
<li v-for="todo in todos"  v-bind:class="{ completed: todo.isActive }" v-on:click="checked">
  {{ todo.task }}
</li>
```

In the checked function you may not be able to modify the isActive property of the todo in place, in which case it may be a little more complicated, but I’m sure this gives you the gist.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marcus. When I use your code, I this console error: 
`vue:6 ReferenceError: todos is not defined
    at bn.checked (main.js:13)
    at Fe (vue:6)
    at HTMLLIElement.n (vue:6)
    at HTMLLIElement.Gr.o._wrapper (vue:6)`

Comment: I think there was a typo in my checked function. See edited answer above.

Comment: The function since to work because I added a console.log at the beginning & it prints the message.